# Why is 'the period' marked as letter T?

Tags: soft-question, frequency, notation, conventions

I'm not a native English speaker and I was wondering, why 'the period' got the letter $T$.
I've asked myself the question when I was thinking about stuff related to the frequency. I.e.:

- $f$ - frequency
- $v$ - velocity of a wave
- $a$ - acceleration

all of those have 'generic' markings, but not 'the period'. Was the letter $T$ used to somehow relate to 'time' the *period* describes? (I just need an acknowledgement really)

Comment: I agree with you conclusion about $t$  and time, but I'll let native English speaker to confirm it as an answer.

Comment: I think so - it seems nicely symmetric since in many equations you would write something like $x=\sin(\frac{t}{T})$ - the time variable t increases until it gets to big T, then things repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, what if they thought about it this way:
Let's put ***t*** for time (latin: tempus) and since time and period are connected (I would think of the period as the smallest time a cyclic phenomena requires to complete one full cycle) let's just denote period with ***T*** as ***t*** is already taken.

Comment: Yes, this looks like a logical move (bc why time got the letter t if T (period) is already derived from 'tempus'). I'll mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say it's form latin *tempus* - http://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentia

Comment: +1 This sounds reasonable, as in time physics was starting, Latin was *lingua franca* in all of the sciences.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, a number of websites suggest that the T for period is for time.

> [Wikipedia: The period, usually denoted by T, is the length of time taken by one cycle, and is the reciprocal of the frequency f:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency#Period_versus_frequency)

See also:

> [Period refers to the time it takes something to happen.](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/waves/u10l2b.cfm)